# Azure Log Analytics query does not return any results

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

I am trying to run a query on the logs in Azure Log Analytics workspace but don't see any data for any duration. Any idea why?

```
Alert 
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1h)
| summarize count() by AlertSeverity, bin(TimeGenerated, 1d)
```

Comment: Do you have anything hooked up to the Log Analytics workspace? Do you have anything configured to hit the Alert table?

Comment: I have several metric alerts and i was trying to see the information about those alerts. I later realized it only stores alert information of log search based alert rules

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [Alert table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/alert) in Log Analytics contains information about alerts created by log alerts rules and SCOM alerts collected through Alert Management solution.

You can [view and manage your metrics alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric#view-and-manage-with-azure-portal) from the Azure portal by navigating to: `Monitor > Alerts > Total alerts` and looking at the ones which have Signal Type as `Metric`.